# MVC model child list null on post unless using TextBoxFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am displaying the list Rooms in a table just for display and if the user is happy with the display they can then export it to pdf (they can't change anything on this page though)

My main issue here is that Rooms is null when I submit the form.

Now I know that if I change `@Html.ValueFor` to `@Html.TextBoxFor` etc. and post the form, Rooms has a value, which is great, but I do not want textboxes displayed on this page, labels or values is all I need.
I have tried `@Html.DisplayTextFor` but it is the same result, null in Rooms.
Can anybody suggest how I can achieve what I need?

**Controller**

```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult GeneratePdf(CommissionReportViewModel model)
   { 
       // Some other processing
   }
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class CommissionReportViewModel : ApiCredentials
{
    public string Organiser { get; set; }

    public string EventName { get; set; }

    public string EventDate { get; set; }

    public BookingPages Bookings { get; set; }

    public double TotalCommission { get; set; }

    public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
    public List<CommissionReportRooms> Rooms { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
    @for(var i = 0; i < Model.Rooms.Count();i++)
    {

        <tr>
            <td>@Html.ValueFor(m => Model.Rooms[i].DelegateName)</td>
            <td>
                @Html.ValueFor(m => Model.Rooms[i].FirstDate, "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")

        </td>
            <td>@Html.ValueFor(m => Model.Rooms[i].Nights)</td>
            <td>@Html.ValueFor(m => Model.Rooms[i].RoomType)</td>
            <td>@Html.ValueFor(m => Model.Rooms[i].GrossTotal,  "{0:0.00}") @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => Model.Rooms[i].Currency)</td>
            <td>@Html.ValueFor(m => Model.Rooms[i].Rate, "{0:0.00}%")</td>
            <td>@Html.ValueFor(m => Model.Rooms[i].Commission, "{0:0.00}") @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => Model.Rooms[i].Currency)</td>
            <td></td>

        </tr>
    }
```

Comment: You could have hidden fields containing the values, these would be submitted but wouldn't be visible, or you could use a textbox with a `readonly` attribute for the display.

Comment: The textbox with a readonly attribute is kind of what I thought too, I didn't really want to have loads of hidden fields but if there isn't another way then fair enough

Comment: You should not be generating hidden inputs. You sending a whole lot of extra data to the client and then posting all back again unchanged (degrading performance and opening yourself to over-posting attacks. In the POST method, get the collection again from the repository if you need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only certain HTML elements actually get submitted such as inputs and select lists. If you're just displaying text on the screen then this will never get submitted using the browser's form submission.

Options

1. Use hidden fields using the Html.HiddenFor helper (this generates hidden inputs which get submitted)
2. Use AJAX which will give you more flexibility over what data is sent to your controller

> they can't change anything on this page though

The whole HTML markup is on the client so they can change anything they want! If you are worried about this you should consider getting your controller to retrieve the booking data from session/database.

Comment: yes I understand that.  I think option 1 is the way to go thanks